# How to get rid of first specific string in JS

Tags: javascript

For example, I have some string data as below.

```
const a = '(@) Apple (ac)' // there is a space after ')'
const b = '(*) Com(yes)'
const c = '(ac) DC (ho)'
const d = '(%)MS' // there is no space after ')'
const e = 'yes man(ho)'
```

And I want to modify this letter as below.

```
const a = 'Apple (ac)'
const b = 'Com(yes)'
const c = 'DC (ho)'
const d = 'MS'
const e = 'yes man(ho)'
```

So I tried to do this using this.

```
var res = str.substring(0, 1);
```

I can get '(' or I m thinking use split.

```
const words = str.split(();
```

But I don't know how can I get rid of '(something)' these parethesis entirely.

If you give me some advice, i appreciate you. Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: I have edited my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use regex to achieve that; `substring` won't work easily since the `extra` part might exist or not, so you need to check it before applying but this
`getRidOfExtra` will do the job;

regex explanation:

> `(\([^\)]*\))` => pattern for `(some_charachters)`

> `(\([^\)]*\))?` making it optional by adding `?`

> `\s?` one optional whitespace character

> `(.+)` rest of the string

and this `matches[matches.length - 1]` will return the latest match group which is `(.+)`

```js
const a = '(@) Apple (ac)' // there is a space after ')'
const b = '(*) Com(yes)'
const c = '(ac) DC (ho)'
const d = '(%)MS' // there is no space after ')'
const e = 'yes man(ho)'

function getRidOfExtra (str) {
   let matches = str.match(/(\([^\)]*\))?\s?(.+)/);
   return matches[matches.length - 1];
}

console.log(getRidOfExtra(a))
console.log(getRidOfExtra(b))
console.log(getRidOfExtra(c))
console.log(getRidOfExtra(d))
console.log(getRidOfExtra(e))
```

Comment: Sorry. I edit my question. Bcz it can be possible there is parethesis behind. But if there is behind, it doesn't be changed.

Comment: @ThomasJason updated the answer accordingly, adding some explanation now

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to remove the parentheses at the start of the string (and optional following whitespace):

```js
var str = "(@) Apple (foo)";

str = str.replace(/^\([^)]*\)\s*/, "");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry. I edit my question. Bcz it can be possible there is parethesis behind. But if there is behind, it doesn't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like that:

```
const a = "(@) Apple"
var res = a.substring(a.indexOf(')')+1).trim();
```

This will take the index of the ")" and trim your string so you will be left with `Apple`.

Comment: Sorry. I edit my question. Bcz it can be possible there is parethesis behind. But if there is behind, it doesn't be changed.

Comment: That is fine. Than you can use one of the answers with he regex :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a regex including a capture group

```js
const getAfterParanthesis = (str) =>  {
  return /(\(\S*\))?\s?(.+)/.exec(str)[2];
};

console.log(getAfterParanthesis('(@) Apple'));
console.log(getAfterParanthesis('(@) Apple (ac)'));
console.log(getAfterParanthesis('(*) Com(yes)'));
console.log(getAfterParanthesis('(ac) DC (ho)'));
console.log(getAfterParanthesis('(%)MS'));
console.log(getAfterParanthesis('yes man(ho)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect all your variables in an array and do the following loop:

```
var myConsts =  = [a, b, c, d, e];

//Do this two times to remove every parenthesis.
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
     myConsts.map(element => element.replace(/\(.*\)\s*/, ""));
}
```